# How can I create an array of a divided number in PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm

I want to create an array in PHP by dividing a number. So for example when I have the number `200` and I divide it through `0,10`, I need to get an array with 2k entries of `0,10`.

But when I have a division like `233,12 / 0,10`, I also need the array but the last possible entry needs to be a bit higher so that it fills the sum up.

Actually I have no code. This is too complex for me. Maybe someone has an idea. I've did everything around this but got really stuck here...

```
$number = 200;
$divider = 0.10;
```

Comment: I didn't get `but the last possible entry needs to be a bit higher so that it fills the sum up` this part, can you explain more ?

Comment: So your arrays would look like: array(0.10, 0.10 ,0.10 ..... 0.10) and (0.10 x 2330 times and the last one: 0.12). Is that correct? The amount of elements in your array is the floor of the result of the division?

Comment: @VictoriaRuiz Correct!

Comment: could also use `range(0, 200 / .10, .10)`, but you might want to opt for a simple for loop instead of just filling an array

Answer (score 1):

So you want to have an array with 2k entries each having the value 0.1 in them?

So something like

```
$number = 200;
$divider = 0.1;
$totalArraySize = $number / $divider;
$result = [];
$result = array_fill(0, $totalArraySize, $divider);
```

However to make it slightly bigger in case of (for example) 233,12/0,1 you would simply need to ceil() the $totalArraySize to round it up to the nearest full integer. And to make sure that the last entry has the difference you basicly need to calculate it. You get it by taking what you expect to be the sum and subtract the values you know to be right. So (totalSize - 1) * 0,1 .. would give you in this example 233,1 so the last entry would be then 233,12 - 233,1 = 0,02

```
$number = 233,12;
$divider = 0.1;
$totalArraySize = ceil($number / $divider);
$wasRoundUp = $number % 1 === 0
$result = [];
$result = array_fill(0, $totalArraySize, $divider);
if ($wasRoundUp)
    $result[$totalArraySize] = $number - (($totalArraySize - 1) * 0,1)
```

Edit: Actually I realised that my logic to see if it was round up was wrong. I cannot rely on modulo 1 division here as 233,1 would be divisible by 0.1 in an even amount. So we need to check if totalArraySize != ($number / divider).
So new code would be

```
$number = 233,12;
$divider = 0.1;
$totalArraySize = ceil($number / $divider);
$wasRoundUp = $totalArraySize != ($number / $divider);
$result = [];
$result = array_fill(0, $totalArraySize, $divider);
if ($wasRoundUp)
    $result[$totalArraySize] = $number - (($totalArraySize - 1) * 0,1)
```

Edit 2:
To reflect the question in the comment and "fix" an issue with the code here's the new answer. To fill up the last entry it now takes the divider value and not hardcoded 0.1 which would have to be changed correctly. And due to floating point calculations you would need to round the last value to two decimal points. I cannot guarantee if thats the best aproach tho to avoid the floating point rounding issue you might get there

```
$number = 164.85;
$divider = 0.2;
$totalArraySize = ceil($number / $divider);
$wasRoundUp = $totalArraySize != ($number / $divider);
$result = array_fill(0, $totalArraySize, $divider);
if ($wasRoundUp)
$result[$totalArraySize] = round($number - (($totalArraySize - 1) * $divider), 2);
```

Comment: Nice! Could it be possible that there is the rounding missing for the last element to 2 digits?

Comment: Somehow it's not working with the the number 164.85 and 0.2 as separator. The last number is too big `82.28`. Any idea?

Comment: For the last * 0,1 you would need to pass in the divider. However be aware that with floating point rounding issues you will not get exact the answer you want. you might be able to round the last result to 2 decimal points to have it correct. I will update my answer ontop to reflect both